# Cassandra Error: Column timestamp is required

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am learning Cassandra with Java, and I've tried to run the Hotel sample in this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010852.do (Cassandra: The Definitive Guide). But because this sample used some libraries with obsolete version (cassandra-0.7.0, libthrift-0.9.0) and it's impossible to compile it; so I've modified it by switching to latest version (cassandra-all-1.2.4 and cassandra-thrift-1.2.4) and it is compiled successfully. But I cannot run it to enjoy the result. This error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" InvalidRequestException(why:Column timestamp is required)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20833)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:964)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:950)
    at com.cassandraguide.hotel.MainApplication.insertAllHotels(MainApplication.java:41)
    at com.cassandraguide.hotel.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:28)
```

Could you please help me solve this? Thank you so much.
Here are my project's details:

1. Libraries to use:
   cassandra-all-1.2.4 and cassandra-thrift-1.2.4
2. Database:
   I used apache-cassandra-1.2.3 and also installed DataStax OpsCenter on my machine.
   I created the keyspace "hotelier" manually on OpsCenter follow this description:

   keyspaces:

   - name: Hotelier
     replica_placement_strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.RackUnawareStrategy
     replication_factor: 1
     column_families:
   - name: Hotel
     compare_with: UTF8Type
   - name: HotelByCity
     compare_with: UTF8Type
   - name: Guest
     compare_with: BytesType
   - name: Reservation
     compare_with: TimeUUIDType
   - name: PointOfInterest
     column_type: Super
     compare_with: UTF8Type
     compare_subcolumns_with: UTF8Type
   - name: Room
     column_type: Super
     compare_with: BytesType
     compare_subcolumns_with: BytesType
   - name: RoomAvailability
     column_type: Super
     compare_with: BytesType
     compare_subcolumns_with: BytesType
3. Here is my codes:

Connector class:

```
package com.cassandraguide.hotel;

import static com.cassandraguide.hotel.Constants.KEYSPACE;

import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra;
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.InvalidRequestException;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;

//simple convenience class to wrap connections, just to reduce repeat code
public class Connector {

    TTransport tr = new TSocket("localhost", 9160);

    // returns a new connection to our keyspace
    public Cassandra.Client connect() throws TTransportException, TException, InvalidRequestException {

        TFramedTransport tf = new TFramedTransport(tr);
        TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tf);
        Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
        tr.open();
        client.set_keyspace(KEYSPACE);
        return client;
    }

    public void close() {
        tr.close();
    }
}
```

MainApplication class

```
package com.cassandraguide.hotel;

import static com.cassandraguide.hotel.Constants.CL;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra;
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column;
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ColumnOrSuperColumn;
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Mutation;

public class MainApplication {
    private static Cassandra.Client client;
    private static Connector connector;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        connector = new Connector();
        client = connector.connect();
        insertAllHotels();
    }

    public static void insertAllHotels() throws Exception {
        // Try to put some dummy data
        String columnFamily = "Hotel";

        // row keys
        String cambriaKey = "AZC_043";

        // conveniences
        Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> cambriaMutationMap = createCambriaMutation(columnFamily, cambriaKey);

        client.batch_mutate(cambriaMutationMap, CL);

    }

    private static Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> createCambriaMutation(String columnFamily, String cambriaKey)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // set up columns for Cambria
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Column cambriaNameCol = new Column(getByteBuf("name"));
        cambriaNameCol.value = getByteBuf("Cambria Suites Hayden");
        cambriaNameCol.timestamp = timestamp;
        Column cambriaPhoneCol = new Column(getByteBuf("phone"));
        cambriaPhoneCol.value = getByteBuf("480-444-4444");
        cambriaPhoneCol.timestamp = timestamp;
        Column cambriaAddressCol = new Column(getByteBuf("address"));
        cambriaAddressCol.value = getByteBuf("400 N. Hayden");
        cambriaAddressCol.timestamp = timestamp;
        Column cambriaCityCol = new Column(getByteBuf("city"));
        cambriaCityCol.value = getByteBuf("Scottsdale");
        cambriaCityCol.timestamp = timestamp;
        Column cambriaStateCol = new Column(getByteBuf("state"));
        cambriaStateCol.value = getByteBuf("AZ");
        cambriaStateCol.timestamp = timestamp;
        Column cambriaZipCol = new Column(getByteBuf("zip"));
        cambriaZipCol.value = getByteBuf("85255");
        cambriaZipCol.timestamp = timestamp;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn nameCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        nameCosc.column = cambriaNameCol;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn phoneCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        phoneCosc.column = cambriaPhoneCol;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn addressCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        addressCosc.column = cambriaAddressCol;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn cityCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        cityCosc.column = cambriaCityCol;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn stateCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        stateCosc.column = cambriaStateCol;

        ColumnOrSuperColumn zipCosc = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        zipCosc.column = cambriaZipCol;

        Mutation nameMut = new Mutation();
        nameMut.column_or_supercolumn = nameCosc;
        Mutation phoneMut = new Mutation();
        phoneMut.column_or_supercolumn = phoneCosc;
        Mutation addressMut = new Mutation();
        addressMut.column_or_supercolumn = addressCosc;
        Mutation cityMut = new Mutation();
        cityMut.column_or_supercolumn = cityCosc;
        Mutation stateMut = new Mutation();
        stateMut.column_or_supercolumn = stateCosc;
        Mutation zipMut = new Mutation();
        zipMut.column_or_supercolumn = zipCosc;

        // set up the batch
        Map<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>> cambriaMutationMap = new HashMap<ByteBuffer, Map<String, List<Mutation>>>();

        Map<String, List<Mutation>> cambriaMuts = new HashMap<String, List<Mutation>>();
        List<Mutation> cambriaCols = new ArrayList<Mutation>();
        cambriaCols.add(nameMut);
        cambriaCols.add(phoneMut);
        cambriaCols.add(addressMut);
        cambriaCols.add(cityMut);
        cambriaCols.add(stateMut);
        cambriaCols.add(zipMut);

        cambriaMuts.put(columnFamily, cambriaCols);

        // outer map key is a row key
        // inner map key is the column family name
        cambriaMutationMap.put(getByteBuf(cambriaKey), cambriaMuts);
        return cambriaMutationMap;
    }

    private static ByteBuffer getByteBuf(String str) {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `cambriaNameCol.timestamp = timestamp;`

use `cambriaNameCol.setTimestamp(timestamp);`

This is a thrift way of implementing timestamp upgraded since 0.7 version.

And one more thing, why are following thrift? There are so many simple API's out there.